# How to find one's Istha Devata from his horoscope?

Tags: scripture, gods, astrology

One such method found [here](http://astrovastutips.com/know-your-ishta-devata/) is given by Rishi Parasara & is as follows:

> Atma Karaka is the planet that has the highest longitude in one’s
>   natal Chart. Atma Karaka in Navamsa is called the “Karakamsa”. The
>   12th from the Karakamsa determines the “Istha Devata”. The 12th house
>   from the karakamsa is called the “Jivanmuktamsa”. This is the house
>   signifying the emancipation of the soul and we have to examine this
>   house in order to find one’s Ishta Devata. If there is a graha in the
>   Jivanmuktamsa, it signifies the Devata. If there are more grahas than
>   one, we choose the strongest. If there is no graha in the
>   Jivanmuktamsa, we can see whether any Grahas are aspecting the 12th.
>   If no Grahas aspect it, we can take the 12th Lord as Ishta Devata.
>
> Below are the presiding deities for each planet who will be your Ishta
>   Devata as per your Horoscope.
>
> Sun– Vishnu/Rama/Shiva Moon– Krishna/Shiva/Parvati Mars–
>   Hanuman/Subramanya/Sri Narasimha Mer–  Vishnu Jup–  Vishnu/Sri
>   Vamana/Dattatreya/Sai Baba Ven–  Maha Lakshmi/Parashurama/Maa Gouri
>   Sat–  Shani Dev/Hanuman/Kurma/Shiva/Vishnu Rahu—Maa Durga/Varaha Ketu–
>   Ganesh/Matasya Ascendent– Kalki

My question-Is this the only authentic & generally accepted method for determining one's Istha or more such methods are available in scriptures?

Comment: As per Hinduism there is only one ishta deva for all people. That is Shiva/Allh/GOD. They are one only. And Parvatimata and her various incarnations are mother to all people around world. That is why she is called Jagadamba.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental work of *Ishta Devata* is to guide the native towards the path of *moksha*.

While rigorously, the method finding of *Ishta* is the same as above, several other methods have been described in traditions of *Jyotish* to find devatas that guide the native towards liberation.

**Jyotisha Shastra**

> As *12th* house refers to *moksha*, see the position of the *12th* lord with respect to the *12th* house. For example, if *12th* lord is in the *8th* house, *Vishnu* or *Krishna Bhakti* is prescribed, as *8th* is *9th* from *12th*. Similarly, *12th* lord in *3rd* can show *Devi Bhakti*, as it is *4th* from the *12th*.

- The above technique is to be applied on *Rashi Chakra.*

> As *Ketu* is the planet that ultimately grants liberation, planets conjuct *Ketu* in the *Navamsa* can show the *devata* that guides the native towards liberation. If no planet is conjunct, the *lord* of the *rasi* of *Ketu*  is considered.

- Clearly this can be applied only on *Navamsa* chart. Further elaboration can be found [here](https://srigaruda.com/ganapati/).

> The most well defined method is finding the planet *12th* to the *rasi* occupied by *Atmakaraka* in the *Navamsa*, which is clearly described in the question.

---

**Tantra Shastra**

One must keep in mind that *Ishta* in *Jyotish* is a very well defined and narrow concept. If one explores further in *Tantra Shastras*, we find a reference to *Ishta Devi* in the form of **Mahavidya**. Here, the meaning of *Ishta* should be understood as '*Ishwara* who protects from *kashta*', which is a much wider and meaningful translation.

- The *shloka* elaborating the same is given below:

[image]

> **Translation**: The *Dasa Mahävidyä* are the *ista devatä* of
> the *graha*: *Mätangi* for *Diväkara* (Sun); *Bhuvanesvari* for
> *Candra* (Moon); *Bagalä devi* for *Kuja* (Mars); *Parasundari*
> (*Tripurä sundari*) for *Budha* (Mercury); *Tärä* for *Brhaspati*
> (Jupiter); *Kamalätmikä* for *Sukra* (Venus); *Daksinä Käli* for
> *Sani* (Saturn); *Chinnamastä* for *Rähu* and *Dhümävati* for
> *Ketu*. [In another *tantra*, *Bhairavi* is the *Mahävidyä* for
> *lagna*.]

If any signification of the above planets is damaged, corresponding **Mahavidya** has to be propitiated within the strict guidance of a *Guru*.

- Source: **Jyotish Digest, Pt. Sanjay Rath (2006)**.

Comment: What I have read is Bhuvaneswari presides over Shukra and Kamala over Chandra.

Comment: Hmm, I'll relook and tell.

Comment: The verses you have quoted clearly say for Shukra its Kamala and for Chandra its Bhuvaneswari. So it must be the correct rulership. May be some other Tantra have a slight different opinion and which I have read.

Comment: Yeah. What I meant is I'll look at other Tantra texts if possible, and tell.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.

Comment: Today I asked Sanjay Rath a question, from which Tantra did he quote this shloka? I am waiting for his answer, the name of Tantra.