# Why is monday considered an important day in Shaivism?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shaivism

Monday is usually thought of as a holy day dedicated to Shiva. Why is it so? Is there any significane of monday according to our Shastras?

Comment: Soma is moon and Somnath i.e. lord of Soma/moon is another name of Shiva, Monday or Moon Day is Somavaar, isnt it obvious? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somnath_temple

Comment: @ManuKumar but is there anything in shastra to confirm this? Afaik Pradosh Vrat is there in shastras but People fast on Monday to please Shiva. Is this a recent phenomena or confirmed by shastras?

Comment: People had earlier discussion also on this forum, Shiva, Devi, Vishnu etc., are gods of later Puranas and tantras, though there are mentions of Rudra, Vishnu as brother of Indra in Vedas. Celebration of week itself is later addition, as actual Vedic and astrological dates are considered from Purnima to Amavaysa, hence Puranas have mention of Ekadashi Vrat/fasting (11th day in lunar cycle) not any vrat of Monday or Friday.  The position of moon impacts humans, not just random days of week. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirjala_Ekadashi

Comment: Its a placebo, the concept is similar in Abrahamic religion where Muslims pray in Mosque on Friday/Jumma while Christians in Church on Sunday. Just power of faith.

Comment: @ManuKumar i agree with you on weekdays being to specific Gods being a later formation..but Vishnu,Shiva,Devi and others are Vedic Gods though this was elaborated in Puranas leading to sectarianism within Hinduism.

Comment: @ManuKumar I think assigning weekdays to Hindu Gods like Monday for Shiva Tuesday for Hanuman etc started as the abrahmic practice of sabbath https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbath Though references of Vedic astrological tithis being important for particular Gods are present in Shastras.

Comment: exactly, Sabbath started in Judaism, first one in Abrahamic religion from Moses celebrating it on Saturday through ten commandments, it came later to Vedic India. Accurate predictions of vedic astrological horoscope is based on position of moon on birth date, day are irrelevant later things. Gods are associated with planets like Kartikeya with Mars, Laxmi with Shukra etc.,

Comment: @ManuKumar i doubt if ever came to India as such(except christians and muslims) Maybe this practice was started by Hindu priests to counter abrahmic religions

Comment: 7 Planets are associated with days, hence association of deities of respective planet was followed later. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/how-to-find-ones-istha-devata-from-his-horoscope Abrahamics borrowed from hinduism, well planets are made by nature, so knowledge is of God.

Comment: @ManuKumar the question you quoted is referring to finding ishtadeva from astrological charts. This really doesn't answer my question as I have asked the practice which almost all Shaivas agree on. While ishtadeva are found out individually. Further the list includes sai baba too which makes it even more dubious.

Comment: he copied from somewhere, read the answer in original Brihat Prashar hora Shastra, http://jyotishvidya.com/ch33.htm , what shaivas or vaishnavas or shaktas or all these sects believe and contradict each other or follow mindlessly in Kaliyga, i am not concerned, God is one and his manifestations are Veda-Vedanta, astrology, Samkhya, Yoga, Nyaya, Mimamsa etc., six schools of original Shastras of Hinduism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_philosophy

Comment: If you pray to only one god , you can pray him in all days. But many Hindus pray every day and pray multiple Gods. It is convenient to pray different Gods on different specific days. After assigning the days to each specific God, the arguments for choosing that particular day of the week are built up. Acceptance of this procedure brings a great deal of uniformity in households and temples and celebrating festivities. As far as god concern Monday is just like any other DAY. I don't think God wants us to keep only one particular day is good for Praying.