# Which Hindu scriptures talk about pacifying ill effects of Rahu by worshipping Lord Hanuman or Goddess Durga or Goddess Chinnmasta?

Tags: hanuman, durga, rahu

There are many sources available on internet (see [this](http://indiafacts.org/dasha-mahavidyas-ii-chinnamasta/) which claim that worshipping Goddess Chinnmasta pleases Rahu, so the ill effects of Rahu are pacified by worshipping her. Many websites (like [this](https://vedicakshat.com/2018/09/07/shri-rahu-insight-remedies/))write that worshipping Goddess Durga also pacifies Rahu.

Also, [this](https://vedicgoddess.weebly.com/vedic-astrology---mirror-of-the-sky-blog/-rahu-by-yogi-ananda-saraswathi) website tells that worshipping Lord Hanuman also pacifies ill effects of Rahu because Lord Hanuman rescued all the 9 planets from the demon Ravan.
What is the scriptural basis for any of this information ? In which Hindu scriptures it is written that worshipping either of the three deities mentioned above is a remedy for Rahu ?

What is the mythological story behind it ? Like for Shani (Saturn), it is known that worshipping Lord Hanuman saves one from the ill effects of Shani because Lord Hanuman broke the false pride of Shani once.
Please quote authentic references from scriptures. Not just folklore stories. Thanks.

Comment: Chinnamasta is a remedy for Rahu as per Tantras. Similarly for Saturn its Kali, for Jupiter its Tara etc. For this you can get scriptural reference. Also for Rahu usually the remedy is considered as Durga/Chandika (not sure about the reference here). Hanuman is a remedy for Saturn not Rahu.

Comment: @Rickross I am looking for the exact scriptural reference, which says worshipping Devi Chinnmasta or Devi Durga pacifies Rahu. I searched on internet but could not find any.

Comment: You can see the answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44490

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the link you have shared contains just the pic of the relevant shloka/verse, but does not mention the exact scripture and its chapter number from which it is taken.

Comment: Yes, it has just the relevant slokas. But the slokas are definitely from Tantras. Since Tantras are mostly lost now, it is hard to get exact verse nos. in many cases. Many books quote only some slokas from Tantras that are now mostly lost. For example, Viswasara Tantra is now lost. But quotes from it are still found in some books like Brihat Tantrasara. You can ask the answerer there. He might know which Tantra the slokas are from.