# Is isht devta determined by birth kundali or a person can choose it?

Tags: gods, puja

Is Insht devta predecided by janm kundali or we have freedome to choose the diety as our isht devi or devta?

Comment: Related -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10644/4732

Comment: Don’t know if this is correct or not, however from what I understand, RamaKrishna said several times to to choose the form that you adore the most. More by instinctively going towards  the form you naturally feel affinity. That’s how it ended up w/ me for bhakti marg. My name alone would have predicted something very different. I guess I feel like, trust your instincts if you feel strongly towards one deity, but that is advice from a total beginner on bhakti path 

Comment: @Rickross It gives detailed procedure. I just want to know if I have a choice or it dtrictly decided by my birth

Comment: It is determined by our birth just like every other things and later it becomes our choice when we think we have chosen our Ishta but in truth it is already determined. @Rambhakt